How to get data from plugin?
How to get data from plugin (joomla 4,joomla 5), before it is saved and read from the database?
I would be grateful if you provide a solution.

You need to provide more details or context around your question. Plugins don't necessarily read and save data to the database so without knowing what you are trying to achieve there is no starting point for anyone trying to assist you to begin with providing a useful answer.

@Irata How can we get the form information inside the plugin before saving it? Or to say that, for example, you want to change the value of one of the fields before saving the form information, how can you do this?

You should edit your original question with more detail on what exactly it is you are trying to do or achieve, even the information in the above comment could be added to your Question.

In general terms your plugin would likely use one or more of the onContent methods to get the data from the Form, e.g. onContentBeforeSave. This is for J3 but still relevant, https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content
